# Python: connect to already opened console application

Tags: python, console, popen

I have an interactive console application and I need to work with it using Python (send commands and receive output). The application is started by another one, I can't start it from Python script.

Is it possible to connect to already running console application and get access to its stdin/stdout?

Ideally the solution should work both in Windows and Unix, but just Windows version would also be helpful. Currently I am using the solution found here
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/440554/
but it doesn't allow connecting to existing process.

Thanks for any input,

Comment: Do you want to take over control of the stdin/stdout? Observe them only? What do you want to do after you have connected to it?

Comment: @aychedee
Yes, I need to take control over stdin/stdout. The simplest example of the situation I have would be already running cmd.exe programm, which I need to connect to and send commands (like dir, copy, etc.) and receive output.

Comment: I have the same problem. I have a program started in a win32 console by some other program and now I need to read the screen - just a write it in a log. No need to actually type into the console, just read

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using sockets since they are straight forward for simple/streaming. They are also platform independent.

The most critical point is thread safety where having to pass IO streams between threads/processes tends to be hectic.

If on the other hand you use a socket, a lot can be communicated without adding too much complexity to how the processes work(coding an error prone RPC for instance).

try [Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) or

[example](http://www.binarytides.com/python-socket-programming-tutorial/)

Comment: I don't think sockets can be used to connect to a local process (like cmd.exe for instance).

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python) but its not clear whether you want a console(cmd.exe) to communicate with you or your application on cmd.exe to communicate with this new process. The later could be used with sockets. The first, not sure how.